# Scrolling to the top in Custombox modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, modal-dialog

I'm using [Custombox](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/) to open a modal. This modal however can get a little long so I added a "Go To Top" button.

I found [this at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/5530965) and I've been trying different combinations to make the modal scroll back up.

I've tried:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#modal-id").offset().top
}, 800);
```

and a handful of different combinations for getting the offset but I can't get it to scroll to the top of the modal.

Comment: Where is the scrollbar? (on the browser window, or on the modal window)

Comment: @MichaelOakley On the browser.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 Really? When the modal becomes a bit longer, the vertical scrollbar is there and I can manually scroll using my wheel mouse.

Comment: Is there a jsfiddle we could look at?
It looks like the plugin disables the scrollbar on the page.
https://github.com/dixso/custombox/blob/master/src/css/custombox.css#L6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar belongs to the `.custombox-modal-wrapper` element, so you should scroll it, not `<body>` or `<html>`:

```
$(".custombox-modal-wrapper").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#modal-id").offset().top
}, 800);
```

Comment: Hey, this worked! When I tried using a different element I used the `.custombox-modal-container` `div` and it didn't work. How do I determine which element has the scrollbar?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I just inspected the gray background in Chrome DevTools and found out it's this element.

Comment: Both the `.custombox-overlay` and the `.custombox-modal-wrapper` highlight the scroll bar when I inspect those elements.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio But `.custombox-overlay` isn't a parent of the `.text` div (div which contains actual content of the modal), it doesn't have any children at all.